# Linux remove a single underscore before and after a character using command line

Tags: regex, linux, string

How do I remove a single underscore (_) before and after a character?.  I have a large number of files named like

*filename_part_one_-_filename_part_two.file*

To get the filename to the above format I used `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` to lowercase and `rename 's/ /_/g' *` to strip whitespace.  The final step is to remove the underscore before and after the -.  Preferably using a one line command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To substitute `_-_` with `-` use `s/_-_/-/`. You can put it all into one argument to rename:

```
touch "FileName Part one_-_filename_part_two.file"
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/_-_/-/' "FileName Part one_-_filename_part_two.file"
ls *.file
> filename_part_one-filename_part_two.file
```

Comment: I used rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/_-_/-/' * however this is not replacing the _-_ to just this: filename_part_one-filename_part_two.file <- This is how i need the filenames to end up

Comment: @SteveFitzsimons I guess that you want to replace "_-_" with "-"? I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Turns out some of the files had _-_ twice.  Just re ran the command to change them also

Comment: @SteveFitzsimons You can also use the `g` behind the second `s` like behinde the first `s` part, it means `g`lobal and it does replace all occurences.

Comment: I ended up using these commands based on your answer for anyone else looking to use them

Comment: find . -iname "*" |  rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/_-_/-/'  ---> To rename the files recursively


rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/_-_/-/' *   - to rename everything in the current directory